# Does Visual Studio 2010 have a new driver building feature? Or is it only the 2011 Version

Tags: visual-studio, filter, driver

we're creating a filter driver and trying to find the easiest way to build drivers with Visual Studio.  Supposedly the 2010 or 2011 version has some new features and we're trying to figure out which one to purchase.

If anyone has any knowledge about this, it would be greatly appreciated.  And if you have any experience creating filter drivers and install programs, etc, please get in touch with us.

Answer (score 0):

VS2012 (aka VS11) supports building drivers natively. Any prior version can be used as an IDE only and external WDK build is invoked for compilation.